# check if array has this value and then grab it and place it an a variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string like the one below

**20Nov 18:14:xxxxxxxxxx has given 10 points to xxxxx. New bitcoin collection Balance:XXXXXXXX. Ref:675743957424**

I will explode it and it will then be turned into an array.

But I want to check if the array has Ref:675743957424 and then place it inside a variable like for example $a.

I want to do this since the string might change from one point to another so the position of Ref is not fixed.

How Can i obtain such thing?

Thanks.

Edited

I tried not exploding it but instead try grabbing the data see code below

```
<?php
 $line = "20Nov 18:14:xxxxxxxxxx has given 10 points to xxxxx. New bitcoin collection Balance:XXXXXXXX. Ref:675743957424";
 // perform a case-Insensitive search for the word "Vi"

  if (preg_match("/\bRef\b/i", $line, $match)) :
  print "Match found!";
   //how can I grab the Ref part?
  endif;
```

?>

Comment: You want to check just 'Ref' or 'Ref:somenumbers'

Comment: Ref:somenumbers and then I need to place it inside a variable. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```
preg_match ('/Ref:[\d]*/', $line, $matches);
```

The matches will be saved to variable `$matches` and then you can operate with said matches.
The RegExp, you just need to look for string `Ref:` followed by any amount of numbers (`\d` looks for any digit and `*` looks for zero or more ocurrences of the previous operator, digits in this case).

If you know the exact number of digits that you must to find and it is not varying you could use the pattern {NUMBER}, like:

```
preg_match ('/Ref:[\d]{12}/', $line, $matches);
```

This case, you are looking for 12 digits after `Ref:`.

Comment: If you use `preg_match ('/Ref:([\d]+)/', $line, $matches)` then `$matches` will contain 2 values, the full match and the Ref number that I assume is what you need at the end. Something like
 Array
 (
  [0] => Ref:675743957424
  [1] => 675743957424
 )

Comment: If that's what OP looks for, I will gladly accept you to edit my answer, adding that improvement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strpos() to check whether the substring present in the string. If it is true, you can assign that to your variabble. Pleas see the below code, it may help you.

```
 $line = "20Nov 18:14:xxxxxxxxxx has given 10 points to xxxxx. New bitcoin collection Balance:XXXXXXXX. Ref:675743957424";
 $string_to_check ='Ref:675743957424'
 if (strpos($line,$string_to_check) !== false) { //Ref is present
  $a = $line;
 }
```

Comment: This is only valid if the Ref number is always the same, in that case it is easier just to do `$a = 'Ref:675743957424'` which doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, if he can put this as a variable then it will check for any substring.

Comment: By the context, it seems the result of a transaction, there is no way he will know the reference number in advance.